# how to find which project is running in Eclipse programatically

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a Java Application in Eclipse for example. as soon as I click on run button or try to run, I want to get a notification.
I think there must be some API related to runtimeConfiguration of Eclipse but couldn't crack it yet. Any suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could listen to [org.eclipse.debug.DebugEvents](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/debug/core/DebugEvent.html).

You can attach the listener using this code, from [this topic](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/369839/):

```
DebugPlugin.getDefault().addDebugEventListener(<listener instance>);
```