# How to get event for eclipse Run As Launch shortcut

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In eclipse IDE , for any java project , while selecting Run As->Java Application i need an alert like "Eclipse now is running xyz project". How to do this , I am aware of launch configuration delegate , need starting point ......

Comment: Look at these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282581/eclipse-debugger-events http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155762/how-to-find-which-project-is-running-in-eclipse-programatically/19155970#19155970

Comment: Is there any working plugin  or sample available for it??